# Access Parent Schema Value inside Repeater - Filament

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

I am trying to access `field_1` value inside the repeater

```
return $form->schema([
    Select::make('field_1')->reactive()->options(['a','b','c']),
    Repeater::make('repeater_1')->schema([
        TextInput::make('field_2')->default(fn (Closure $get) => $get('field_1')),
    ]),
]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
TextInput::make('field_2')->default(fn (Closure $get) => $get('../../field_1')),
```

https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/forms/fields#using-get-to-access-parent-field-values

Comment: Thanks Dan. I actually found few hours after I posted the question. I forgot to answer it here. Thank you tho :)

Comment: It works thanks. But why do we need '../../' instead of '../' ?

Comment: @RafatRashidRahi Because `../` allows you to access other items in the same repeater and `../../` goes a step further to allow you to access fields outside of the repeater. This is explained in the docs if you read them.